# What is the scope of a function defined outside of a class?

Tags: python, class, oop

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


def foo():
    x += 2
    obj.a += 10

obj = player(0,0)
x = 4

foo()
```

I understand that my `foo` function is not able to assign a value to the local variable `x` since it was previously defined globally outside the `foo` scope. Yet the same problem won't occur for a variable `a` which is an attribute of the instance `obj` from the `player` class, which in turn has nothing to do with the function `foo()`. 
Apart from the error with `x += 2`, I would expect an error in `obj.a`, i.e., I think `foo()` should not be able to modify `obj.a`, but it does! It should have thrown the same error as for `x += 2` perhaps, no?

Comment: Augmented assignment operators are tricky. One the one hand, they behave like method calls: `x += 2` is `x.__iadd__(2)`. But on the other hand, they behave like an ordinary assignment: `x += 2` is recognized as a local name by the parser, so `x` is local throughout the current scope. Neither point of view is sufficient to describe the semantics, because the type of the LHS needs to be considered.

Comment: But if the LHS is not a name, but an attribute lookup, a *different* set of rules applies, because now we no longer have a true assignment statement, but syntactic sugar for a call to some class's `__setattr__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can't call `x += 2` because x is not yet defined in your code. You can read `x` as a global var, or you can change it's value using `global`.

If you run your code, you'll get the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

What it is saying to you is: I know there is a global x variable in your code, but you can't change it here. But, if you wish, you can create a local variable here named x, and then change it's value. Or, if you really want to modify the value from the global variable, use the global keyword, so I'll know exactly what you want to do.

Declaring it locally:

```
def foo():
    x = 0
    x += 2
    obj.a += 10

obj = player(0,0)
x = 4

foo()
```

With global:

```
def foo():
    global x
    x += 2
    obj.a += 10

obj = player(0,0)
x = 4

foo()
```

**Now, why `x.a += 10` works?**

Because you are not changing the x object at all.

As mentioned by John in his answer, the same error would occur if you were changing the object itself, not its properties.

if you try to run the code below:

```
def foo():
    obj += 10

obj = player(0,0)
x = 4

foo()
```

You'll get the same error as before:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'obj' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Oh I get it! So it is as if x is seen in the same way as obj from within the function (not obj.a). @John comments is much clearer now... It raises another question though, I am able to modify obj.a and obj.b yet the obj instance is still the same. Modifying the instance is probably through the methods within the class only then? Thank you Rafael!

Answer (score 2):

All augmented assignments effectively desugar to one of three method calls, but only in one case is an actual assignment performed.

1. If the lefthand side is a name, then `x += y` desugars to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`. Because this is an ordinary assignment statement, the parser makes `x` a local variable (unless preceded by a `global x` or `nonlocal x`). Regardless of scope, `x` must already have a value so that the righthand side can be evaluated. In other words, `x` is not a free variable.
2. If the lefthand side is an indexed name, then `x[i] += y` desugars to `x.__setitem__(i, x[i] + y)`. If `x` is not already defined as a local variable, it is a free variable, and so will resolve to the value
   of `x` in the first enclosing scope.
3. If the lefthand side is an attribute lookup, then `x.a = y` desugars to
   `x.__setattr__('a', x.a + y)`. Again, `x` is a free variable unless a local variable `x` already exists.

Comment: This is cool. I already sort of knew this stuff, but didn't really understand how it worked. The opposite of a free variable is a bound variable, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is apples to oranges. An example which shows you the behavior you're expecting would be:

```py
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __add__(self, value):
        self.a += value

def foo():
    obj += 10

obj = player(0,0)
x = 4

foo()
```

Python permits you to read global variables inside of `foo`, but not redefine them. The statement `obj.a += 10` only reads the variable of `obj` from the global scope (even though it sets a value on the instance of `obj`) so it is allowed. `x += 2` attempts to redefine the value of `x` which is a global, so it is not allowed. This `foo` will work because we are only reading `x` but not redefining it:

```py
def foo():
    obj.a += 10
    y = x + 10
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more the relation to my question? In your example, obj + integer works because you defined the __add__ function.  calling foo() will raise an error because it does not see the __add__ method from obj instance which is interesting but it does not clarify my question at all. If a change obj += 10 to obj.a += 10 I am back to the problem.  I understand that obj.a is the same as x because type(x) == type(obj.a) but apparently obj.a seems to be the same as if I declared 'global x' within foo().

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an attribute of `player` instance while `x` is a variable or simply value. When you are modifying `x` in the function, it is in local scope and results in `NameError`. But `obj` is an object in global scope and when you modify `a`, you are simply updating its attribute, you won't get any error here.

Comment: This is what I suspected. But is it a python behavior that atributes are by default global variables hence they are always able to be modified whereas a simple variable x = 4 cannot. I think I got it

Answer (score -1):

Without using one of the keywords `global` or `nonlocal`, a function can *read* but not *assign a new value to* a variable outside of the function's own local scope. Let's consider these two cases:

- For `x += 2`, this is an attempt to assign a new value to the global variable `x`, so it is not allowed.
- For `obj.a += 10`, it is the variable `obj` which is global; `obj.a` is an object attribute, not a "variable" in this sense. The way `obj.a += 10` is evaluated is something like this: first look up the object referenced by the variable `obj`, and then add 10 to the attribute named `a` belonging to that object. Since this only *reads* the global variable `obj` and does not attempt to *assign a new value* to `obj`, it is allowed.

Comment: I don't think this explanation is correct: `x += 2` is *not* interpreted as an attempt to assign a new value to the global variable. Essentially, that *is* the entire problem (which, as you correctly mention, happened because we don't use the `global` keyword). But it isn't that python doesn't allow you to modify or assign a new value to the global variable, it's just the ambiguity has to be accounted for and resolved first.

Comment: Python defaults to trying to interpret the `x` inside the function as a local variable unless it's instructed otherwise.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh It is an attempt *by the programmer* to assign a new value to the global variable `x`, not an attempt *by the interpreter* to do so. The mechanism by which it is not allowed is that since the function contains an assignment to `x`, Python treats `x` as a local variable and therefore doesn't look up the global variable of that name when evaluating `x + 2`, hence a `NameError` is raised even though the expression `x + 2` would have evaluated successfully otherwise.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Python actually defaults to treating variables as either local or nonlocal, but that behaviour is different for a variable which the function contains an assignment to. That behaviour is then different again if `global` or `nonlocal` is used.